# Under what condition on $A$ is the following true: $\lambda_{min}(A) \|x\|_2^2 \leq x^T Ax \leq \lambda_{max}(A) \|x\|_2^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I remember in a numerical analysis class, the prof showed the class,

$$\lambda_{min}(A) \|x\|_2^2 \leq x^T Ax \leq \lambda_{max}(A) \|x\|_2^2$$

where I am assuming that $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda_{min}(A)$ is the min eigenvalue (ditto max eigenvalue), and $A$ has some nice property.

**I am trying to find out for which $A$ the above inequality holds (and hopefully why).**

Through some posts on MathSE I was directed to the **Courant-fisher min-max theorem**, and I looked up a version in Horn and Johnson's Matrix analysis textbook.

[image]

I can see if you shift the $x^Tx$ from the denominator to the other side, then you have something like that inequality. But this looks like a serious overkill and I cannot immediately see any direct reduction from Courant-Fischer to the original set of inequality.

Any reference helps!

Comment: I'm not sure if there are other cases, but it is along the right path. Notice that it is a Hermitian matrix, equal to its own conjugate transposed (the complex version of a symmetric matrix). Symmetric matrices can be shown to be diagonalizable, so if you right $x$ in terms of eigenvectors $v_i$, $Ax = \lambda_1 v_1 + ... + \lambda_n v_n$ ($\lambda_1$ largest, $\lambda_n$ the smallest). Since they are diagonalizable, each eigenvector is orthogonal, so $x^TAx = \lambda_1 |<v_1, v_1>|^2 + ... + \lambda_n |<v_n, v_n>|^2$. Using unit $v_i$ and x, this is max for $x=v_1$ and min for $x=v_n$

Answer (score 2):

**Claim.** Suppose $n\ge2$ and $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ has a real spectrum. Then $\lambda_\min(A)\le x^TAx\le\lambda_\max(A)$ for every real unit vector $x$ if and only if
$$
Q^TAQ=\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}\lambda_1&0&0\\ 0&\lambda_n&0\\ \hline0&0&B\end{array}\right).\tag{1}
$$
for some orthogonal matrix $Q$, some real numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_n$ and some matrix $B\in M_{n-2}(\mathbb R)$ such that
$$
\lambda_1\le\lambda_\min\left(\frac12(B+B^T)\right)
\le\lambda_\max\left(\frac12(B+B^T)\right)\le\lambda_n.\tag{2}
$$

**Proof.** Suppose $\lambda_\min(A)\le x^TAx\le\lambda_\max(A)$ for every real unit vector $x$. Then
$$
\lambda_\min(A)\le\min_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TAx.\tag{3}
$$
However, when $u$ is a unit eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_\min(A)$, we also have
$$
\min_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TAx\le u^TAu=\lambda_\min(A).\tag{4}
$$
Therefore equalities hold in $(3)$ and $(4)$. As $x^TSx=x^TAx$ for every real vector $x$, we obtain
$$
\lambda_\min(A)=\min_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TSx=u^TSu.
$$
As $S$ is symmetric, the minimum of $x^TSx$ on the unit sphere is achieved only at eigenvectors corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of $S$. Therefore $u$ must also be an eigenvector of $S$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_\min(S)$. It follows that
$$
u^TSu=\lambda_\min(A)=\lambda_\min(S)=\min_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TSx= \min_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TAx.\tag{5}
$$
Similarly, let $v$ is a unit eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_\max(A)$. Then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $S$ and an analogous equalities to $(5)$ hold.

Suppose $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent. For any vector $w\perp u$, we have
$$
\begin{cases}
\langle A^Tw,u\rangle=\langle w,Au\rangle=\langle w,\lambda_\min(S)u\rangle=0\\
\langle Sw,u\rangle=\langle w,Su\rangle=\langle w,\lambda_\min(S)u\rangle=0\\
\langle Aw,u\rangle=\langle(2S-A)w,u\rangle=0\\
\end{cases}\tag{6}
$$
In particular, if we write $v=au+bv'$ for some unit vector $v'\perp u$, then $Av'\perp u$. However, since $V=\operatorname{span}\{u,v'\}=\operatorname{span}\{u,v\}$ is an invariant subspace of $A$, we must have $Av'\parallel v'$, i.e. $v'$ is also an eigenvector of $A$. But the eigenvalues of $A|_V$ are $\lambda_\min(A)$ and $\lambda_\max(A)$. Hence we must have $v'$ must be an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_\max(A)$. That is, we may assume that $v=v'\perp u$.

The analogous equalities to $(6)$ also hold if $u$ is replaced by $v$ and $w\perp v$. Therefore, if $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix whose first two columns are $u$ and $v$ respectively, then $Q^TAQ$ is in the form of $(1)$. Moreover, we have
$$
\lambda_\min\left(\frac12(B+B^T)\right)\ge\lambda_\min\left(\frac12(A+A^T)\right)=\lambda_\min(S)=\lambda_\min(A)
$$
and similarly $\lambda_\max\left(\frac12(B+B^T)\right)\le\lambda_\max(A)$. Therefore $(2)$ also holds with $\lambda_1=\lambda_\min(A)$ and $\lambda_n=\lambda_\max(A)$.

If $u$ and $v$ are linearly dependent, then $\lambda_\min(A)=\lambda_\max(A)$. Therefore, all eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to some $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. By a similar argument to the above, we get
$$
Q^TAQ=\pmatrix{\lambda&0\\ 0&B}
$$
for some orthogonal matrix $Q$ and some $B\in M_{n-2}(\mathbb R)$. As $A$ has a real spectrum, we may choose $Q$ such that $B$ is upper triangular. Hence the diagonal elements of $B$ are equal to $\lambda$. However, as
\begin{aligned}
\lambda&=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TSx=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TAx\ge\max_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TBx
=\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\frac12x^T(B+B^T)x\\
&\ge\min_{\|x\|_2=1}\frac12x^T(B+B^T)x=\min_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TBx\ge\min_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TAx=\min_{\|x\|_2=1}x^TSx=\lambda,
\end{aligned}
we have $\frac12x^T(B+B^T)x=\lambda$ for every unit vector $x$. Hence $\frac12x^T(B+B^T)=\lambda I_{n-1}$, i.e. $B=\lambda I_{n-1}+K$ for some skew-symmetric matrix $K$. But $B$ has a real spectrum. Hence $K$ must be zero and $A=\lambda I_n$. But then $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold for any orthogonal matrix $Q$. The necessity of $(1)$ and $(2)$ is thus proved.

Conversely, suppose $(1)$ and $(2)$ are true. By replacing $A$ by $B$ in $(4)$, we have $\min_{\|y\|_2=1}y^TBy\le\lambda_\min(B)$. Hence
$\lambda_\min\left(\frac12(B+B^T)\right)
=\min_{\|y\|_2=1}\frac12y^T(B+B^T)y
=\min_{\|y\|_2=1}y^TBy
\le\lambda_\min(B)$.
Therefore, $(2)$ implies that $\lambda_1\le\lambda_\min(B)$. Similarly, we also have $\lambda_\max(B)\le\lambda_n$. Hence we must have $\lambda_\min(A)=\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_n=\lambda_\max(A)$. It follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $\lambda_\min(A)\le x^TSx\le\lambda_\max(A)$ for every real unit vector $x$. Since $x^TSx=x^TAx$, the conclusion follows.